# Working around MS Exchange's policy for forwarding to external email address

Tags: exchange, forwarding

Our company just moved to MS Exchange server from Domino. I do not want to connect my personal phone to the company's exchange server just because the company can remote wipe my phone. When we were using Lotus Notes, I was able to setup a rule to forward selected (notifications from a web service) emails to my gmail address and was working very well. In outlook I was able to set up a similar Rule but it did not work.

After searching a little bit I found that it's a setting in Exchange server and by default (And for security purposes) it does not allow rules to forward emails to external email addresses. i know this policy is there for a reason but is there any way to work around it?

Now I found [Google Calendar Sync](http://www.google.com/support/calendar/bin/answer.py?answer=89955) that syncs my work calendar with my google account calendar. Is there something similar for email?

Thanks,

Comment: Working around IT policy not a great idea.  Grounds for termination in many places.

Comment: @DaveM I absolutely agree with that.  @shadowfoxmi I'm curious - where did you read that there is a default policy preventing forwarding in Exchange?  From experience, I've never heard of a policy, let alone a default one, that prevents the forwarding of emails to a mail-enabled contact.  It would surprise me if they can't just set up a simple forward on the Exchange Server.  I would speak to your IT guys and ask them to add it for you.

Comment: Doesn't your Exchange server support IMAP for email access? Remote wipe doesn't work with that.

Comment: I would definitely ask your IT guys to setup a forward in Exchange if you can, as it will bypass this setting.  If they won't do it because of "company security policies", DaveM is dead right with his comment.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. It's not easy to get in contact with IT, thought I'm reaching out. At my previous 2 jobs in different parts of the same organization I was able to forward using STMP or IMAP without issue.

Only since I started working in this new job with a new IT group have I had the problem.

There is no reason why the security should be any different. I've been looking for ANY way to get gmail and exchange mail in the same place.

Comment: What I want to know is WHY is this considered more secure? Why is blocking me from having my email forwarded or redirected to another address AND blocking any kind of access for IMAP and STMP a good idea?

What kind of abuse are they targeting?